# Rename file which store on Drive D: [Robotframework]

Tags: robotframework

I want to rename my file that store on drive D:.
By use Name from gettext.

[image]

[image]

Please advice me for solutions.

Comment: Should be provide more detail than this. Example your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Robotframework you can use keyword **Move File** for rename any file with the same source destination.

```
 Move File   oldName.txt    newName.txt
```

[Document Reference](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Move%20File)